# How to clear all textboxes in a Web Form? (The name 'form1' does not exist in the current context)

Tags: asp.net, textbox, controls

I'm a new to ASP.NET and don't have much experience with programming.
I have found a method that should clear all textboxes in a Web Form. But for some reason form1 isn't recognized. I would like to know, if in the code below form one should refer to the exact form I'm coding in or whether if it's a class.

I tried replacing the name form1 to the one in the codebehind file, the error disappears but the text remains in textboxes after the clear button is clicked.

```
void cleanFields()
        {
            foreach (Control item in form1.Controls)
            {
                if (item is TextBox)
                {
                    TextBox t = (TextBox)item; t.Text = "";
                }
            }
        }
```

I expect that textboxes are cleared after the button is clicked. Yet their content remains after clicking clear, which event is wired to the method above. The same happens after the page reloads.

Comment: Share your form tag code located on aspx page

Comment: try use `Page.Controls`

Comment: Or `Page.Form.Controls`.

Comment: <%@ Page Title="Cidades" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Cidades.aspx.cs" Inherits="Frota_LET.WebForm1" %> @MohsinMehmood is this is it? Unfortunately, Page.Controls and Page.Form.Controls didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textboxes were inside a content placeholder. The code below worked.

```
        void cleanFields()
    {
        foreach (Control item in Page.Form.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").Controls)
        {
            if (item is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)item).Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }

    }
```